# Django - overriding login css

Tags: css, django

My login form container is currently being overridden by some css thats applied to the body

using google dev tools i have found the culprit but my attempt to override is failing...

so on the login form we have

```
<body class=" login"
  data-admin-utc-offset="3600">

<div id="header-bar">
    <div id="header-content">
        <div id="header-meta-bar">
            .....
    </div>
<!-- Container -->
<div id="container">
```

then in the css for container i can see

```
.login #container {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    border-radius: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 28em;
    min-width: 300px;
    margin: 100px auto;
}
#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 980px;
    padding: 0;
}
div {
    display: block;
}
```

all those styles applied by .login #container i dont want, they are breaking my layout.

so i thought i could overide them with the below in the admin_overrides.css file

```
.login #container{
    border:0;
    width:100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

but they dont apply, they get stricken out in the dev tools.

can anyone tell me how i can override this style please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `!important` before `;` to your commands which you want to force to override others. As long it (and the file where it is in) got loaded at last and don't interfere with another `!important` prefixed commands after them, it should work:

```
.login #container{
    border:0!important;
    width:100%!important;
    margin: 0!important;
}
```

Good luck ;)